# Firefox and Chrome do not share clipboard - what's wrong?

Tags: google-chrome, copy-paste, firefox

I seem to experience issues with clipboard - copying from Firefox into other apps works ok, but from Firefox into Chrome doesn't.

Copying from other apps into Chrome behaves erratically.

Any idea on why this is?

macOS High Sierra
Version 10.13.13

Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87

Firefox Quantum
60.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: I use: Firefox 60.0.2 (64-bit) and Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit). I've never had a problem doing this, and I do it frequently. Only thing I have noticed is that some text fields in online forms do not accept "paste" for reasons I don't understand. Are these form fields you're seeing this in, or just in general?

Comment: @Seamus, if a text field does not accept command-V, try control-click/Paste.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue ongoing now for about a year I'd say.  The only workaround I've found is to restart the browser(s) which is a hassle.  I'd really like to find a solution for this.  I thought it was my older MacBookPro (6 years old) but I just upgraded to a brand new one and the same problem happens on a daily basis.

I'm using macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6
Chrome version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Firefox version 62.0 (64-bit)